# MVC Why is my TextBoxFor not displaying a Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This should be real simple but I don't why this is happening? I have a piece of my ViewModel as:

```
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

I have the TextBoxFor using this model field. Why doesn't it show a Textbox? There is no value yet but why doesn't it show a Textbox for the user to type in? I just get the label.

```
 <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
        </div>
```

Controller is:

```
 public ActionResult OptIn()
        {
            PrefCenterEntities db = new PrefCenterEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var attributes in db.HarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = attributes.AttributeName,
                    Value = attributes.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
            }

            foreach (var sel in db.SelectedHarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = sel.CustomLabel,
                    Value = sel.HarmonyAttribute_ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selList);
            }

            OptInViewModel viewModel = new OptInViewModel
            {
                Attributes = listSelectListItems,
                SelectedItems = listSelItems
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Generated code for Error Message is there!

```
<div class="row">
            <label for="ErrorMessage">Error Message:</label>
            <input id="ErrorMessage" name="ErrorMessage" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
```

It wouldn't be with this CSS rule I applied to a TextAreaFor before to get it to show up would it?

```
 <p>Item Caption Text (140 Characters. HTML not allowed.)</p>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ItemCaptionText,10, 60, new { style="border-color: grey!important; border-width: 2px!important; border-style: solid;"})
```

Comment: Do you have any css declarations that might be hiding elements with the row class? If that's not it, I'd post your entire controller here...

Comment: It's also worth checking the HTML produced and seeing what's there for ErrorMessage (if anything)

Comment: I added my Controller but it doesn't do anything with this TextBoxFor

Comment: The generated code shows an HTML input element. Why doesn't it show up?

Comment: Does your `row` class have something like `height: 10px; overflow-y:hidden`?

Comment: Sounds like some "user error". Where did you get the generated html from? If from browser (or even browser inspector), then you just should play with your css. It has nothing with MVC and Controllers then.

Comment: check once in your browser console  to see if any client side errors are showing up or remove all the css styles and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

just like the comments say try taking out the parent `<div>` like so:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
```

is the label even showing up??   if that doesn't work , you can try something like this :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ErrorMessage, new { style = "position:absolute;z-index:10000;width:300px;height:25px;" } )
```

just to overwrite any styling that may be hidding the text box

Comment: The label was always showing up, just not the outlines of the textbox

Comment: The textbox still doesn't show up even with  the style you have here